# Instance variable Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

I have the following two methods in my CommandsController

```
class CommandsController < ApplicationController
.
.
.

def userslist
    @command = Command.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @users_list = @command.users.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end

def deleteuser
    user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    user.commands.destroy(@command)
    flash[:success] = "Utente eliminato dalla lista con successo"
    redirect_to list_path(@command)
end
.
.
.  

end
```

When I execute deleteuser method I receive the following error:

`Command(#31369720) expected, got NilClass(#19349600)`
related to line `user.commands.destroy(@command)`
which means that @command is nil, but why is it so? Isn't @command an instance variable visible by all methods in my class?

P.S. To call deleteuser method I have to go through userslist method, so @command is certainly not nil.

Comment: @command can not be available to deleteuser method. you need to declare again

Comment: but why can't @command be available? it's an instance variable, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@command` instance variable is not set when you call `deleteuser` method, so it evaluates to `nil`.

The reason you have this error is you probably misunderstand how the Rails controllers work. Rails creates new instance of your commands controller with every request regarding this controller, so even if you set `@command` instance variable in previous action, with new request it is `nil` again.

I suggest learning some Rails/Ruby basics and conventions (including naming conventions).

Comment: but it is set by the userslist method previously

Answer (score 0):

You can make another private method to declare `@command` and call it in before_filter after the declaration of the controller class